# Generic bottleneck detector (Linux Servers)

Tags: linux, performance-analysis

I search a generic hardware bottleneck detector.

The tool should monitor all processes on the server for 24 hours.

Then it should report where the bottleneck could be.

Required features:

- open source
- works for linux servers

List of possible bottlenecks:

- Amount of CPU
- Single CPU speed
- IO performance
- Network
- ...

A tool which just shows a graph of cpu/io usage does not solve my question.

The question is: where does the most hardware related waiting occur?

Answer (score 1):

A robust solution would be to use **collectd** with an appropriate frontend, for example **Grafana**. This requires a working a database setup.

---

A simpler solution would be to use **icinga2**. This requires you to at least write or download a script/plugin for network monitoring, CPU/Memory/IO scripts are included in the default installation.

On many linux distributions there are packages named along the lines of `monitoring-plugins` or `nagios-plugins` which include more useful monitoring scripts.

---

*I personally use both methods in conjunction, icinga for reporting problems and Grafana for analyzing them afterwards, though Grafana is theoretically able to do both.*

Comment: Yes, the tools you mention could solve this. But finally there is still a lot of human expert knowledge needed to understand the data. If I want to, and have time, then I can analyse the data and draw a conclusion. But I am lazy :-) With other words: Your answer is a good start. It shows how to fetch data. I search for an automated analysis of the data.

Comment: Your question seems underspecified then. Icinga an grafana can send you a report mail/sms whatever if a defined scenario occurs i.e. 10min of >80% load. What exactly are you looking for then?

Comment: I updated the question. See the last two sentences of it. Is it more clear now? If not, please tell me.

Comment: Well the most waiting is likely to be IO blocking, mostly disk that will be, a overloaded network will usually result in requests being dropped, as will high CPU load (for webservers anyway), even with the updated question icinga (or nagios or any other mainstream monitoring application) with plugins or collectd with grafana and mail notifications is the way to go

you can easily specify circumstance under which you will receive a notification, which still seems to be exactly what you are looking for